# Do I have to type nullable column in seeder in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Just a quick question - I can't test it by myself right now so that's the reason why I ask.

If I create a migration and I will add a column that can take NULL values

```
$table->text('col_that_can_be_nullable')->nullable();
```

then in case of seeding, do I have to define the same column (even when I don't want do seed it with anything) in the array or can I just simply skip it?

```
Something::create([
    'col_mandatory' => 'lorem',
    'col_that_can_be_nullable' => '' // Do I have to put it
    (...)
```

or

```
Something::create([
    'col_mandatory' => 'lorem',
    (...)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply skip it because it's nullable.

Since Eloquent is an ORM that generates the query, if you skip this column in the seeding, then the query will not reference your column. Thus it will be inserted as `null` by the DBMS.